# SQlite Data is not updating into listview

Tags: android-studio, android-listview, android-sqlite

> SQlite Data is not updating into listview. no error showing just not save the edited value. when I click the list view it will open with the inserted value to edit but when I push the update button it won't update. Any Solution for my Problem ??

> ListDataActivity.java

```
 listView = findViewById(R.id.listViewId);

            loadData();

        }


            public  void loadData() {
                //Create an arraylist so that i can load the data to add in the  arraylist
                ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();

                Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.showAllData();
//jodi kono cursor e row na thake
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no data is available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                listData.add(cursor.getString(1) + " \t " + cursor.getString(2));
            }
        }
                    
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.textViewId, listData);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedValue = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    String name = cursor.getString(1);
                    String surName = cursor.getString(2);
//                    listData.add(cursor.getString(1) + " \t " + cursor.getString(2));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ListDataActivity.this, UpdateActivity.class);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Value : " + selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    intent.putExtra("id", id);
                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                    intent.putExtra("surName", surName);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }

        });
```

> UpdateActivity.java

```
 id = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("id");
        String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        String surName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("surName");

        updateName.setText(name);
        updatePhone.setText(surName);

updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = updateName.getText().toString();
                String surName = updatePhone.getText().toString();

                if(view.getId()==R.id.updatebuttonId){

                    ListDataActivity.databaseHelper.updateInformation(id,name,surName);
                    startActivity(new Intent(UpdateActivity.this,ListDataActivity.class));
                    finish();

                }

            }
        });
```

> DatabaseHelper.Java

```
public int updateInformation(long id, String name, String surName) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(NAME,name);
        contentValues.put(SURNAME,surName);
        String whereArgs[] = {""+id};
        int count = sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,NAME+ "=?",whereArgs);
        return count;

    }
```

Comment: wrong way updated the value ?? anyone helps plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that you are trying to update using a WHERE clause that is effectively saying update the row where the NAME = the id that has been passed *(likely to never find such a row)*.

You need to change the 3rd parameter passed to the `update` method to be the name of the id column. So you want something like :-

```
int count = sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,ID+ "=?",whereArgs); //<<<<< ID instead of NAME
```

- Note the above assumes that the String Constant ID contains the name of the id column. So you may have to change ID accordingly.

Comment: I have solved this bug sir, but when I update the particular data it won't the value, or even if I delete my row it removes only the previous row. can you look at my problem, sir?

Comment: @ayazkhan the way SO works is you ask a question, if the answer is helpful then you indicate this by ticking the answer (or the best/preferred/most suitable). If you have other issues then you ask a question. However, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68649633/sqlite-database-updating-and-deleting-the-data-when-i-click-the-listview-data/68659005?noredirect=1#comment121340903_68659005 (it's an answer to a very similar question).